# Freezing and De-Activating a Salesforce Service Cloud User Account Through the REST API

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, user

I'm trying to use one of our existing enterprise user administration tools to also provision and manage Salesforce Service Cloud user accounts using the Salesforce API.  I am able to provision a user through the API, but I see conflicting information about whether or not the API can be used to de-activate or freeze an account.

Has anyone been able to successfully do this through the API?  REST is preferable but if SOAP is the only option I'll take that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IsActive` field on User object to deactivate a User [using SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm).

> Description
>
> Indicates whether the user has access to log in (true) or not (false). You can modify a User's active status from the user interface or via the API.

To freeze Users, you need to use the [`UserLogin` objec](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userlogin.htm)t and the `IsFrozen` field. For pointers, you can refer to this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187696&language=en_US&type=1).

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  I was using the HTTP POST method.  Updates to existing records must be made with the PATCH method.